# How to link a query with an iframe

Tags: ms-access, iframe, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusionbuilder

I know how to manually create an iframe by linking each image to a name.

```
<a href="0604-013037 - Financial Aid.png" target="viewframe">3501 Nebraska Ave. NW</a>

<iframe name="viewframe" style="display:block;height:1000px;width:1000px"></iframe>
```

Then using ColdFusion I can also create a table of data.

```
Number    Name    State
```

What I want to know, if there is a way to link a query with an iFrame? So that each piece of data is linked with an image that would appear in the iFrame. So that when you select the information from the table an image would appear.

```
<cfquery datasource="AccessTest" name="qTest">
    SELECT Name, State, Number
    FROM List       
</cfquery>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
        Displaying a Query in a table
    </title>
</head>

    <div id="content">
        <h1>
            Displaying a Query in a Table
        </h1>
        <table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Number</b></td>
            <td><b><!---Bolds --->Name</b></td>
            <td><b>State</b></td>
        </tr>
        <cfoutput query="qTest">
            <tr>
                <td>#qTest.Number#</td>
                <td>#qTest.Name#</td>
                <td>#qTest.State#</td>
            </tr>
        </cfoutput>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: An anchor tag with a target attribute pointing to your iframe should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you would just need to add the desired information from the query to your `<cfoutput>` tags.  Something like this:

```
<cfoutput query="qTest">
    <tr>
        <td>#qTest.Number#</td>
        <td>#qTest.Name#</td>
        <td>#qTest.State#</td>
        <td><a href="#qTest.unique_image#" target="viewframe">#qTest.unique_description#</a></td>
    </tr>
</cfoutput>
```

Notice that I am making some assumptions here:

1. That your query can also return the path and file name of the unique image that you would like for each link
2. That your query can also return the unique image description that you would like displayed for each link

Comment: If I am using Access as my database would I set it up as a link?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Shouldn't matter what database you are using, it is the data that we are after. Where are your links/images stored?

Comment: Btw don't use access this is no longer supported as a web database since winfows server 2008 as the legacy drivers are 32 bit only.

Comment: Its in the C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\project

Comment: @MichaelDowney - What I meant was, are your links and/or images stored in a database so that you can query them out?  My answer is assuming that the info is stored in a database so that you can just loop over the query results and output the unique links and descriptions.  Does that help?

Comment: If its saying "HTTP Status 404 - /wwwroot/Travel/Test4.png"..."description The requested resource (/wwwroot/Travel/Test5.png) is not available.
" How do I fix that?

Comment: It seems to work if the image is in the DB file. Is there a way to get it to link without having it in the db File

Comment: Remember the href wants a url, not physical directory, so based on your example it might be something like `www.yourdomain.com/Travel/Test4.png` or just relative like `/Travel/Test4.png`. (Assuming that the wwwroot folder is your site's web root folder.)

Answer (score 1):

If you change this:

```
<a href="0604-013037 - Financial Aid.png" target="viewframe">3501 Nebraska Ave. NW</a>
```

to something like this:

```
<cfoutput query="yourquery">
<a href="IFramePage.cfm?IDToProcess=#IdFromYourQuery#" target="viewframe">
#text from your query#
</a>
</cfquery>
```

You are off to a good start.  On page, IFramePage.cfm, have some code like this:

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(url, "IDToProcess")>
code to get and display data 
<cfelse>
Maybe leave it blank, maybe display something
</cfif>
```